# PHP - Openssl enable --with-openssl[=DIR]

Tags: php, apache, mysqli, phpmyadmin, openssl

I have Windows 10/x64, Apache24, MySQL 8.0, PHP 7.2.10

**I'm trying to connect database:**

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'test123', 'ninja_project');
if (!$conn) {echo "Connection error:" . mysqli_connect_error();}
```

**But keep getting this warnings:**

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): PHP was built without openssl extension, can't send password encrypted in C:\Users\User\www\phptutorial\ninjapizza\index.php on line 3

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\Users\User\www\phptutorial\ninjapizza\index.php on line 3 Connection error:Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

**I've already done some things to solve the issue:**

1. Checked solution through same topics already discussed on stackoverflow, but found nothing helpful in my case.
2. Enabled openssl in php.ini extension=openssl.dll
3. Specified directory extension_dir = "c:\php\ext"
4. Checked openssl status through CMD '''php -i''' - openssl support => enabled
5. Checked openssl modul through CMD '''php -m''' - got openssl in list
6. Checked localhost/index.php - openssl enabled
7. Checked file php-cli.ini on my PC - don't have one
8. I tried to rename $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost' to $conn = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1'. Doesn't work. Same problem.
9. Granted All privileges to User.

I have `openssl.cnf in directory C:\php\extras\ssl`
I have `openssl.cnf in directory C:\Apache24\conf`
I have installed OpenSSL on Windows and have openssl.cnf in directory `C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin`

I specified directory for OPENSSL_CONF different ways

```
set OPENSSL_CONF=c:\php\extras\ssl\openssl.cnf
set OPENSSL_CONF=c:\Apache24\conf\openssl.cnf
set OPENSSL_CONF=c:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\cnf\openssl.cnf
```

According to this page https://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php I must to compile PHP `--with-openssl[=DIR].` But I have no idea how to do this properly. I'm only on the level to learn PHP and MySQL.

I restarted Apache many times. Don't know what can I do else!